# create a branch on the 'lost' commit of a force pushed branch

Tags: git, github

I have a github repo that got an accidental force push on a branch.

The PR of this branch shows both the new and the old commit and i even can browse the files of this commit - so everything is still be there.

Can i somehow add a branchname to this commit, so that it can get checked out normally (and at the end correct the messed up initial branch)?

Comment: So let me get this straight, you/someone accidently pushed a commit to an existing branch, and now you want to move the new commit to a different branch and restore the original branch to where it was before the new commit was added?

Comment: there was a messed up force push from someone else on this branch. the old commit is not in my reflog. but for sure in the ref log of github, because I can still see and navigate the commit and its parents (and since it is documnented within the PR, I do not think that it gets gc-ed). I now want to be able to check out this commit to clean up the mess.

Comment: If you have the sha of said commit, you can `git fetch origin <sha>; git switch -c newbranch <sha>`

Comment: If you (ore someone) had the correct remote branch at some point: `git reflog origin/thatbranch`

Comment: An addition to @LeGEC comment. The short hash in case of fetching orphaned commit will not work, you need full hash.

Comment: @LeGEC thank you! - the `git fetch origin <sha>` was the missing piece for me. I did not know how to checkout this out-of-tree commit. If you add an answer with this, I will accept it.

Comment: It will be helpful to use diagram or sample branch names to illustrate your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the complete sha of said commit, you can run :

```
git fetch origin <sha>
git switch -c newbranch <sha>
```

as commented by @kadewu : the `sha` in `git fetch origin sha` needs to be *the complete sha* (40 chars), otherwise git will try to interpret it as a reference name.

---

Also worth noting : if you (or anyone else) had the correct state of the remote branch at some point (eg: after a `git fetch`, or a `git pull` on any branch), you can find that correct commit by looking at :

```
git reflog origin/thatbranch
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a branch using GitHub's API, then you can fetch and checkout that branch.

> `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"ref":"refs/heads/<new-branch-name>", "sha":"<sha>"}' https://api.github.com/repos/<namespace>/<repo>/git/refs`

https://objectpartners.com/2014/02/11/recovering-a-commit-from-githubs-reflog/